# MongoDB sorting by condition

Tags: mongodb, sorting, conditional-statements

Hello guys i'm stuck in one condition where i need to sort the data that matches some conditions and then sort them by it's priority bases i.e
first i want to sort the data via it's priority in descending order and then sort them if priority is 1 (high) sort the document via createdAt field else via it's date field.

i currently create one aggregate by myself but it's not returning the correct data.

```
model.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      jobId,
      deprecated: false,
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      document: "$$ROOT",
      sort: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: ["$priority", 1],
          },
          then: "$createdAt",
          else: "$date",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      priority: -1,
      sort: 1,
    },
  },
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey guys thanks for your time i solve the issue i use

i just add one field in the $project due to i'm using `document: "$$ROOT"`
so it create document field and store all the data in it, and that is why priority field is not available,

i just add `priority:1` in $project and it includes that field. below i post the working code may be it helps you if you also wants something like that.

```
model.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      jobId: '5c501eed65816d61c6a0af77',
      deprecated: false,
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      document: "$$ROOT",
      priority: 1,  
      sort: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: ["$priority", 1],
          },
          then: "$createdAt",
          else: "$date",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      priority: -1,  
      sort: 1,
    },
  },
])
```